# LINQ error : The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, enumeration

I am working on a LINQ function in which I am using ToList() inside a for loop. At the 1st iteration it works fine but then onward it throws an exception as

> "The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."

The sample code is;

```
for()
{
     functionCall();
}

functionCall()
{
   var query = <<query logic>>;
   query.ToList();
}
```

I searched a lot to fix this but everyone is saying use ToList();
And I am getting error on ToList() itself.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the for iterate over?  I would start looking for the commonality between your inner and outer loop.  Something is trying to iterate over the same thing as the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating the query more than once, why not refactor your code to this..?

```
// Evaluate the query once
var query = <<query logic>>.ToList();

// Do your loop, passing the evaluated results into the function
for()
{
    functionCall(query);
}

functionCall(query)
{
   //Do whatever you need here
}
```

Comment: Actually it's a nested call. This query has to be executed inside for loop. The query output is then used for next operations.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit with your example perhaps?  There are some things to be aware of when executing a linq query inside a loop - .net will not necessarily evaluate it inside the loop so it could be that it gets evaluated later with the same input.

Comment: Not the exact answer but close to it. Thanks for your help.